# How do i make a checkbox visibility false but still have it function. html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, visibility

Here is how i created my Checkbox:

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsFinal, new { @readonly = "true", id = "chkFinal" })

I don't want it read only anymore, but hidden. How can i go about this?

Comment: Why is this tagged as HTML? It's clearly something else.

Comment: Well you could add a @class="" those this checkbox and add css to hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great , its MVC I want to know you want to hide this check box on some event or just want this  as hidden field or you want check box but its should not be visible on page, Let me know I can help you for sure

If you want as hidden field use

```
@html.hiddenfor(model => model.isfinal)
```

If you want to change this box to hidden after some event o you page you can do it with javascript

```
$('#isfinal').css("display","none");
```

If you find this helpful vote it..

Comment: @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsFinal, new { @style="display:none;", id = "chkFinal" }) seems to be working, thanks for the idea +1

Comment: Thanx buddy, if think its best answer for you problem then please vote it as best answer for you, it will help me to mark my presence